# Проверка параметра на пустой список

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется большой SQL запрос для отчета. Для формирования отчета передаются параметры. Один из параметров это список услуг, которые выбирает пользователь. Со временем этот список сильно вырос, и составления отчета по всем услугам сразу стало проблематично.

Пример таблицы

```
id , title
100, name100
101, name101
102, name102
...
```

Ранее часть запроса имела вид

```
SELECT id, title
FROM tbl_service
WHERE id IN (${service_id})
```

В качестве решения данной проблемы попробовал, такой вариант

```
SELECT id, title
FROM tbl_service
WHERE id IN (${service_id}) OR ${service_id} IS NULL
```

В таком варианте отлично работает с одной выбранной услугой или когда ничего не выбрано (выгружает все), но при выборе двух и более услуг возникает синтаксическая ошибка.

Вариант

```
SELECT id, title
FROM tbl_service
WHERE id IN (${service_id}) OR (${service_id}) IS NULL
```

полностью не работает, сразу синтаксическая ошибка при любом параметре.

В настоящий момент временно ввел дополнительную булеву переменную - "Выгрузить все", но пользователям не нравится. Хотят чтобы выгружалось все, если ничего не выбрано.
Сейчас запрос выглядит так

```
SELECT id, title
FROM tbl_service
WHERE id IN (${service_id}) OR ${allservice} = 1
```

Используются NAUMAN SD, Pentaho Report Designer 3.9, MS SQL Server

Прошу помочь с решением, я уже перепробовал все, что смог придумать.

Дополнительно:

Прямой доступ к БД отсутствует. Все взаимодействие через pentaho.

Comment: Как насчет создания хранимой процедуры в SQL Server, которая принимает параметры?

Comment: К сожалению данный вариант не подходит, так как отсутствует прямой доступ к БД по должностному профилю, только через Pentaho

Comment: передавай список в любом вменяемом сериализованном формате (да хоть в CSV) и парси на отдельные значения в CTE.

Comment: Раньше работал с Pentaho, первый запрос спокойно должен обрабатывать всё. Мой совет - либо в параметрах отчёта копайтесь, либо переходите на SuperSet. SuperSet куда быстрее обрабатывает запросы и выглядит более современно